# Using enemy, player and gun position can player shoot enemy?

Tags: mathematics

I was asked this question in an interview last week and I've been thinking about it but I'm unsure how to solve it.

You are on a spaceship and want to shoot the enemy space ship. You have the enemy position, your position, your gun position, the radius of the enemy and the radius of your gun. Assume the normal is facing forward.

So basically the function is like canHit(Vector3 enemyPosition, Vector3 playerPosition, Vector3 gunPosition, float enemyRadius, float bulletRadius)

I figured I would have to subtract the vectors and get the dot product to check if the enemy was in front of the player. Then I thought maybe I should cross the enemy and the gun to see if they intersect and if they don't check if the radius of the bullet plus the gun position is would reach the enemy. I know this is incorrect, so I'm curious how to go about solving this problem.

Comment: You seem to be missing some data. There's no mention of anything that could block the gun orientation or the bullet. Also there's no hint at how you control the gun (with angles or direction vector). So you can get the line from `gunPosition` to the `enemyPosition`, normalize it and that's it.

Comment: Are you looking for [ray-sphere intersection](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=ray+sphere+intersection) tests?

Comment: @Kromster this is all they gave and said to assume there is nothing that can block the bullet and the gun just fires forward.

Comment: @DMGregory this seems to be it, thank you.

Comment: Is either of the actors moving in a given direction, and do bullets have a finite velocity? Looks like a mechanical physics problem, though I'm not sure.

Answer (score -1):

Using Raycast is one solution.

Raycast from the gun and check if the ray cast hits the enemy radius.

Comment: While this sounds like it would work, I'm looking for math based approach. In this scenario on a white board, I could not just say I'll use a raycast.